# Amazon EC2 instance goes offline

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've set up a game server on Amazon EC2. However it is often going offline for ~10 minutes, failing a status check.

Instance reachability check failed at January 31, 2016 at 8:10:00 PM UTC+1 (4 minutes ago)

When it gets back online, it looks like it was just shut off from the internet. I can imagine it can be DDoS attacks from competing servers, but I am not sure how to come to a conclusion about that.

Does anyone have any clue what can cause thi, or how I can debug it?

Comment: Check your logs. Unless you've got a compelling reason to believe someone'd be DDoSing you, that's probably not it.

Comment: Where do I find the logs that could lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you follow the AWS guides, which I found with a simple Google search? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html . There are also many many hits on "Instance reachability check failed". Which of the ideas in those pages have you tried, and what happened when you did?

Comment: @ceejayoz actually, thinking about it... running a gaming server probably is, in itself, reason to suspect you're under DDoS.